# After refrigerating cookie dough overnight, should i leave my dough at room temperature or go straight to the oven?

Tags: baking

I usually leave my cookie dough in the fridge overnight.

After taking it out, should I leave it at room temperature for a while or should I scoop it and go straight to the oven?

Comment: Fridge or freezer? Your question and content aren't the same thing.

Comment: Opp, sorry i mean in the fridge.

Comment: What kind of cookies and how do you like them to turn out?  It depends on your goals, it's not "wrong" to do it either way.

Comment: i want it to be thin and chewy.Taking it out from the fridge and go straight to the oven making it thick and not spreading very much.

Answer (score 3):

**From the Fridge:**

If you can scoop it (some doughs are too hard), go straight to the oven, though you will likely need to give them a minute longer baking time. This is actually beneficial for some doughs that spread a lot and some recipes actually call for a quick refrigeration.  I like to do this with sugar cookies (particularly snickerdoodles) as they don't get quite as spready.

Be careful when you say "for a while" though... most cookie doughs have egg in them and it's best practice to not leave that out for any length of time.

**From the Freezer:**

I also freeze dough (already scooped) and then bake a couple (or 12) at a time when I want a treat after dinner... or lunch or whenever I want a cookie... these can go directly into the oven and will similarly take a little longer to bake. Though, if you freeze the entire batch (without scooping), that won't be possible.

I do this regularly with homemade cookie dough and I've also worked somewhere that made the [Otis Spunkmeyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otis_Spunkmeyer) cookies from the frozen dough balls and the directions clearly state to bake from frozen, do not thaw.

Here is a source that supports this:

[StillTasty.com](http://www.stilltasty.com/articles/view/40)

> How to Freeze Cookie Dough:
>
> •  Wrap unbaked dough tightly with plastic freezer wrap or pack into a heavy-duty freezer bag or an airtight freezer container.
>
> - When you’re ready to bake the cookies, thaw the frozen dough in the container in the refrigerator. (Thawing will take a few hours.)
>
> •   **If you’re making drop cookies, you can also use this timesaving method: drop spoonfuls of cookie dough onto a baking sheet and place in the freezer until the dough is frozen (about an hour). Transfer the dough balls from the baking sheet into a heavy-duty freezer bag or an airtight freezer container.**
>
> - **To bake the cookies, simply place the frozen dough balls directly onto a baking sheet and bake a few minutes longer than indicated in the recipe.**
>
> •  If you’re making sliced cookies: form the dough into a log, as directed in recipe. Wrap tightly with plastic freezer wrap or place log in a heavy-duty freezer bag.
>
> - To bake the cookies, you don’t need to thaw the frozen dough log — just slice off what you need with a sharp knife. Bake the frozen dough for a few minutes longer than indicated in the recipe.
>
> •     Use frozen cookie dough within 4 to 6 months for best quality.